# Fork() executes the same program and has copy same variables - how do the OS keep both in memory, safeguarding each process only access his variables?

Tags: c, linux

Fork() executes the same program and has copy same variables of the father at the moment of the fork, how do the OS keep both process in memory, safeguarding each process only access his variables?

Answer (score 4):

When the kernel creates a new process, it also creates a new *memory mapping*. Initially all *pages* in the new mapping are shared with the parent process, but once pages in the map are modified by the child process those are copied into their own pages.

Useful terms to search for: Virtual memory, on demand paging, memory mapping, shared memory, copy on write.

Answer (score 1):

The OS copies virtual memory space of the forking process (with possible optimizations like copy-on-write).

Answer (score 1):

Fork is a technique that in general makes a separate address space for the child. The child has the same memory of the parent, but they have different PID. So you can distinguish them: specifically fork() returns 0 in the child process and a non zero value (child's PID) in the parent process.